# Cannot access and run batch file commands using java class

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have created a java class to execute a batch file that is in my desktop so that the commands in the batch file will be executed too. The problem is that, i keep getting the error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I have checked the .bat name and the directory. It is correct. When i type `cmd /c start C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop`, windows explorer opens the desktop tab. However when i type `cmd /c start C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/DraftBatchFile.bat`, it gives the error. My DraftBatchFile.bat is in my desktop.

Here are my java codes:

```
public class OpenDraftBatchFile{
public OpenDraftBatchFile() {
    super();
}

/**Main Method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Get Runtime object
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        //Pass string in this format to open Batch file
        runtime.exec("cmd /c start C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/DraftBatchFile.bat");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Why is it that the batch file cannot be executed even if the directory is correct? Someone please help me. Thank you so much.

**These are the codes in DraftBatchFile.bat**

`@echo off
 echo.>"Desktop:\testing\draft.txt"
@echo Writing text to draft.txt> Desktop:\testing\draft.txt`

When i execute the DraftBatchFile.bat by running the java class, i want a draft.txt file to be created in a testing folder that i have created (in desktop).

Comment: Check the PATH environment variable. See the link to change the path
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. What should be added to the Path environment?

Comment: Java PATH directory, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin

Comment: I have already set that

Comment: This should work. Seems you have errors in your batch file

Comment: Hi, i will include the commands in my batch file. Please kindly help to correct me

Comment: please add the batch code by editing your question.

Comment: Here is your error: Desktop:\
Use full path to your desktop instead: C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko it is better to use `%userprofile%\Desktop` as per my answer below because if this is being run on other systems, user `attsuap` will not exist

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, Yes, of course, I agree!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such thing as `desktop:\`

Instead try something like this.

```
@echo off
echo . %userprofile%\Desktop\testing\dblank.txt
@echo Writing text to draft.txt > %userprofile%\Desktop\testing\dblank.txt
```

Comment: I still get the error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` i got no idea why :( i edited the batch file. I edited `runtime.exec("cmd /c start %userprofile%/Desktop/DraftBatchFile.bat");` that line of code in my java class however when i run my java class i still dont get what i want it still gives error

Comment: I want the draft.txt file to be created in the testing folder i have created in my desktop. Actually, i just have to prove, when i run my java class, my batch file is being executed. Is there any other simpler commands that i can put in my batch file to prove that?

Comment: I will create a new batch file instead and try it out

Comment: @SushaNaidu try my batch code now please, I edited my answer I forgot to replace the desktop:\ part in the first echo.

Comment: IT WORKED ! Thank you so much ! :)

Comment: perfect! My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change a directory and create new subdirectory if it not exist. My offer is change .bat file like this:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%userprofile%\Desktop\testing" mkdir "%userprofile%\Desktop\testing"
echo.>"%userprofile%\Desktop\draft.txt"
@echo Writing text to draft.txt>"%userprofile%\Desktop\draft.txt"
```

Also you can create .txt file and write in it text through Java code:

```
    File directory = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"//Desktop//testing");
    if (!directory.exists())
         directory.mkdirs();
    String content = "Writing text to draft.txt";
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"//Desktop//testing//draft.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```